# Drawing shapes using UIBezierPath in swift

Tags: swift, shapes, uibezierpath

I dont know how to draw shape using UIBezierPath.Anyways i tried with lot of ways but did not successes.

I want to make the below shapes[image]

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
func drawSliceInView(view: UIView, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, radius: CGFloat)
{
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.width / 2)
    let startValue = (startAngle * 2 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 360 - CGFloat(M_PI_2)
    let endValue = (endAngle * 2 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 360 - CGFloat(M_PI_2)

    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: radius, startAngle: startValue, endAngle: endValue, clockwise: true)
    path.addLineToPoint(centerPoint)
    path.closePath()

    let sliceLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    sliceLayer.path = path.CGPath
    sliceLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    sliceLayer.backgroundColor = nil
    sliceLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    sliceLayer.lineWidth = 2.0

    view.layer.addSublayer(sliceLayer)
}
```

Usage example:

```
drawSliceInView(self.view, startAngle: -30, endAngle: 90, radius: 50)
drawSliceInView(self.view, startAngle: 90, endAngle: 210, radius: 50)
```

[image]

Comment: Really thank you.How to increase size of the shapes.Because instead of view i want to change the imageview to this shape

Comment: @Lydia, change the radius value.

Comment: Please see edited question Please let me know how to draw that too.

Comment: @Lydia, just calculate the start and end angle. On 3rd image it is 210 and 330 degrees.

Comment: ok.Can i add image to your code.Like   sliceLayer.contents = image is it possible

Comment: @Lydia, your original question was how to draw shapes using UIBezierPath. Now you are asking something completely different, so, please, ask a new question.

Comment: Yes.Sure.Thank you so much